# Not able to pass recipients emails to rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

Right now any team member on a team can send a message to the team. When they send the message it just posts in the team newsfeed. I am working on a story to email the team to notify the team that a message has been sent to the team.

I have the message mailer working, however I am unable to pass the info of the recipients (email and username). Currently I have it hardcoded to send to my email.

Since the original message model has the recipient set to the class Team this information is not available. This information is only available on the class Member. I have tried switching the classes but that breaks other logic.

---

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def create
    @message.sender = current_member
    @team = @message.recipient   
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save    
        format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: 'Your message was sent.' }
        format.json { render json: @message, status: :created, location: @team }
      else
        prepare_team_dashboard
        format.html { render "teams/show" }
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "Member"
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "Team"
  has_many :news_events, :as => :topic

  validates :sender, :presence => true
  validates :recipient, :presence => true
  validates :message, :presence => true

  attr_accessible :team, :team_id, :recipient, :recipient_id, :message, :image

  after_create { news_events.create :team => recipient }
  after_create :message_email_notificitaion

  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => { :thumb => ["200x300>", :png] },
    :default_url => "/assets/empty.png",
    :path => ":rails_env/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style.:extension"

  def message_email_notificitaion
    begin
      MessageMailer.message_notification(self).deliver!
    rescue => ex
      Rails.logger.error "ERROR SENDING EMAIL"
      Airbrake.notify ex
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
 class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Charactr <admin@charactr.co>"

  def message_notification(message)
    @message = message
    team = @message.recipient

    mail(
      bcc: team.members.map(&:email),
      subject: "#{message.sender.username} sent a message to the team."
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you considered moving the delivery of the email to the controller itself rather than an AR callback?

Comment: I did that originally but could not get the email to send at all.

Comment: By "could not get the email to send" do you mean you received an error or what was the issue? Seems like allowing the `message_sent` to receive the arguments you need and passing them in from the controller it would fix the issues you have. Not sure what would cause your email to not be sent. Maybe configuration on your `development.rb`?

Comment: There was no error. It just did not send the email. But the problem is that the recipient is associated with the Team. { belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "Member"
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "Team"} If the recipient had access to "Member" I would be able to pull the recipient email. I am just trying to figure out how to pull the individuals emails from the team.

Comment: I figured it out. I will update the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and updated the code above.

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Charactr <admin@charactr.co>"

  def message_notification(message)
    @message = message
    team = @message.recipient

    mail(
      bcc: team.members.map(&:email),
      subject: "#{message.sender.username} sent a message to the team."
    )
  end
end
```